# Add comment to a specific article

Tags: php, cakephp, blogs

I'm new to cakephp, I just finished the blog/article tutorial and now I am trying to add the comment system to it.

In my comments table I have,
Id, article_Id, name, email, text and created.

I'm trying to add the comment according to the article ID. So let's say a user views a specific article like /view/1, and he can add a comment to that article at the bottom of the page. How can I do that? I hope I'm clear.

This is my add function for my comment:

```
    public function add()
  {
    $comment = $this->Comments->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $comment = $this->Comments->patchEntity($comment, $this->request-   
    >data);
        if ($this->Comments->save($comment)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The comment has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
 $this->Flash->error('The comment could not be saved. Please, try  
  again.');
        }
    }
    $articles = $this->Comments->Articles->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('comment', 'articles'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['comment']);
}
```

And my add view:

```
<div class="comments form large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?= $this->Form->create($comment); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Comment') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('article_id', ['options' => $articles]);
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('text');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
 <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

As you can see, I am selecting my article from my drop down list but I don't want to do that, I want it so that when users view that specific article they can comment directly and view.

Answer (score 0):

Add the comment form on that view page -

```
<div class="comments form large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?= $this->Form->create($comment); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Comment') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->hidden('article_id', ['value' => $articleId]);
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('text');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And set a hidden field for `article_id` with value of the article id.

Comment: I dont have the data in article_id in the first place. I need i need to pass get the article_id from the url or something. Like when users view a article (Localhost/view/1). He can comment on the article based on the url id=1.

Comment: hmm it says "Notice (8): Undefined variable: articleId [APP/Template\Comments\add.ctp, line 14]"

Comment: The form will be on the articles/view page and you have to pass the articleId from the action.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do that? Been searching for solutions but no hope ;(

Comment: just google it.. You will get some tutorials for this.